# How to plot change in C-index over time in R?

Tags: r, cox-regression

The situation: I have a pair of (nested) multivariable survival models (coxph). The new model significantly outperforms the old, with a higher C-index, pretty good net reclassification improvement (NRI), etc. What I would like to be able to do is create a sort of 'discrimination plot', plotting the change in C-index at various follow-up times for each model. Since I don't have an external dataset for validation, I'm guessing a bootstrap validation (to obtain the estimates and confidence intervals) might be helpful.

However, I'm really not sure how to do this. Any pointers would be appreciated.